# Transparent floating window.

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I'm trying to create transparent floating dockable window. But, having difficulting achieving this. Tried Opacity, but no luck.

Here is a snapshot of my code :

```
    // Floating dockable split pane

    SplitPane splitFloating = new SplitPane();

    XamDockManager.SetInitialLocation(splitFloating, InitialPaneLocation.DockableFloating);

    XamDockManager.SetFloatingLocation(splitFloating, new Point(my.XCoordinate, my.YCoordinate));

    XamDockManager.SetFloatingSize(splitFloating, new Size(my.Width, my.Height));





    TabGroupPane tgpFloating = new TabGroupPane();

    ContentPane cpRichText = new ContentPane();

    cpRichText.Content = new RichTextBox();

    cpRichText.Opacity = 0.0;

    tgpFloating.Items.Add(cpRichText);

    tgpFloating.Opacity = 0.0;



    splitFloating.Panes.Add(tgpFloating);

    splitFloating.Opacity = 0.0;



    this.DockManager.Panes.Add(splitFloating);

    this.DockManager.Opacity = 0.0;
```

Comment: The border of window should be opaque, but its content should be transparent. Please help.

Comment: Please help. Trying various ways but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the Infragistics suite, but generally speaking you should set you `Background` to `Transparent` (if you want to be able to click *on* the background) or `{x:Null}` (if you want to click *through* the background).

Also if it's a window (derives from `System.Windows.Controls.Window`), you'll need to set [`AllowsTransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx) to `true` as well, but this might incur some loss of performance.